# Show data in Table in IONIC Popup

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, popup

I try to show data in Table format in IONIC Popup, I google a lot but don't get success,

[image]

Please help

Comment: if table length increase it will not be good method to show in popup. Hve you tried ionic modal ?

Comment: Yes, I tried and I get success also but I need to show date in popup instead of Modal